# How to make firefox run search in new tab rather than window from command line?

Tags: firefox

Basically i want

```
firefox.exe --new-tab --search apples
```

,but it's not how it works, it opens new window.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no 'native' way of doing that.

However, how about `firefox.exe --new-tab https://www.google.com/search?q=apples`? You could replace `google` with your favorite search engine of course. e.g, `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=test`.